# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64, 32, 32) for Tensor u'InputData/X:0', which has shape '(?, 32, 32, 1)'

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, tflearn

I am trying to train model using tflearn and my own data.

I have 19748 greyscale images which I want to train using my model. I used Image_Preloader method of tflearn to input image. And all images are converted into 32*32 size. But when I start the training process I get this error "ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64, 32, 32) for Tensor u'InputData/X:0', which has shape '(?, 32, 32, 1)'"

I have tried everything in my knowledge but I couldn't solve it and there were similar types of question in stackoverflow but they did not work for me.

Here is my code.

```
from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import


import tflearn
import pickle
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.normalization import local_response_normalization
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
from time import gmtime, strftime
from tflearn.data_utils import image_preloader
import numpy as np


dataset_file = 'noww.txt'



X = np.zeros((19748,32,32,1))
Y = np.zeros((19748,10))

X, Y = image_preloader(dataset_file, image_shape=(32, 32),   mode='file', categorical_labels=True,   normalize=True)


network = input_data(shape=[None, 32, 32, 1])


network = conv_2d(network, 64, 3, activation='relu')
network = conv_2d(network, 64, 3, activation='relu')
network = max_pool_2d(network, 2, strides=2)

network = conv_2d(network, 128, 3, activation='relu')
network = conv_2d(network, 128, 3, activation='relu')
network = max_pool_2d(network, 2, strides=2)

network = conv_2d(network, 256, 3, activation='relu')
network = conv_2d(network, 256, 3, activation='relu')
network = conv_2d(network, 256, 3, activation='relu')
network = max_pool_2d(network, 2, strides=2)

network = fully_connected(network, 1024, activation='relu')
network = dropout(network, 0.5)
network = fully_connected(network, 1024, activation='relu')
network = dropout(network, 0.5)
network = fully_connected(network, 10, activation='softmax')
network = regression(network, optimizer='rmsprop',
                     loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                     learning_rate=0.0001)


model = tflearn.DNN(network, checkpoint_path='model_1',
                    max_checkpoints=1, tensorboard_verbose=0)
model.fit(X, Y, n_epoch=200, shuffle=True,
          show_metric=True, batch_size=64, snapshot_step=200,
          snapshot_epoch=False, run_id='model_1')
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

The error says that Tensorflow can't put a Tensor with shape [64,32,32] into another Tensor with shape [?,32,32,1], here `?` means batch size.

Your model can't feed your batch data into `X` variable because they have not same shapes, you should change your `X` shapes.

Change this line `X, Y = image_preloader(dataset_file, image_shape=(32, 32),   mode='file', categorical_labels=True,   normalize=True)`

to

`X, Y = image_preloader(dataset_file, image_shape=(None, 32, 32, 1),   mode='file', categorical_labels=True,   normalize=True)`

Hope that was useful.